# System Wide Hide/Show Keybinding

Tags: key-bindings, window, keymap, gui-emacs

In OSX' iTerm, you can instantly show/hide the window by the (default) <kbd>alt-space</kbd> keys.

How can I configure emacs to have similar functionality? I want to run GUI emacs, and be able to show/hide it on whim.

Comment: Do either of these hide Emacs like you want?  `M-x ns-do-hide-others` and `M-x ns-do-hide-emacs`  To bring it up, you could just put the Emacs shortcut on your dock, and type Control+F3 (to switch focus to the dock) and type emacs quickly and hit the return key (probably just typing the first couple of letters sufficient, depending upon how many icons you have on the dock that begin with the same letters).  You can bind those `ns...` functions to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/index.php) can be used on the Mac to create a global keyboard shortcut to activate Emacs - for example I have F1 to bring up a terminal, F2 to bring up Emacs, F3 to bring up Firefox.  With these in place I don't find much of a need to hide applications as the one appears over the top of the old one, but as the previous poster said, you can bind "ns-do-hide-emacs" to hide it.